# How to make the infobox of a specific marker be opened by default after i click "show map" button ( similar to Airbnb)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a map with markers for all hotels on a specific area and when i click on each marker display the infobox of each hotel. This map opens on modal window.

I would like when I am on the page of a specific hotel and the user clicks on "View Larger Map" button, the map to be displayed with the infobox of that particular hotel open by default without having to click on that marker (like airbnb map).

I tried to change the click event on google maps with  tilesloaded or bounds_changed but it did not work.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function () {...}));

I also tried

```
function onHtmlClick(key){
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[key], "click");
}
<a href="#" class="btn_map location_map_btn properties" data- 
toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="onHtmlClick(1)">View Larger 
Map <i class="icon-location-5"></i></a>
```

but it did not work.

```
 (function(A) {

if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
    A.forEach = A.forEach || function(action, that) {
        for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++)
            if (i in this)
                action.call(that, this[i], i, this);
        };

    })(Array.prototype);

    var
    mapObject,
    markers = [],
    markersData = {
        'Single_hotel': [
        {
            name: 'Villas',
            location_latitude: 37.713490, 
            location_longitude: 20.980900,
            map_image_url: 'img/villas/280.jpg',
            name_point: 'Aeolos Luxury Villas',
            description_point: 'Lorem Ipsum',
            get_directions_start_address: '',
            phone: '+30 2641 085625',
            url_point: 'single_hotel.html'
        },
        {
            name: 'Villas2',
            location_latitude: 37.713490, 
            location_longitude: 20.980900,
            map_image_url: 'img/villas/280.jpg',
            name_point: 'Aeolos Luxury Villas',
            description_point: 'Lorem Ipsum',
            get_directions_start_address: '',
            phone: '+30 2641 085625',
            url_point: 'single_hotel.html'
        }
        ]

    };


        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.859490, 20.925600),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

            mapTypeControl: false,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
            },
            panControl: false,
            panControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
            },
            scrollwheel: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
            },
            streetViewControl: true,
            streetViewControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
            }
            ]
        };
        var
        marker;
        mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_modal'), mapOptions);
        for (var key in markersData)
            markersData[key].forEach(function (item) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.location_latitude, item.location_longitude),
                    map: mapObject,
                    icon: 'img/pins/' + key + '.png',
                });

                if ('undefined' === typeof markers[key])
                    markers[key] = [];
                markers[key].push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function () {
  closeInfoBox();
  getInfoBox(item).open(mapObject, this);
  mapObject.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(item.location_latitude, item.location_longitude));
 }));

});

    function hideAllMarkers () {
        for (var key in markers)
            markers[key].forEach(function (marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            });
    };

    function closeInfoBox() {
        $('div.infoBox').remove();
    };

    function getInfoBox(item) {
        return new InfoBox({
            content:
            '<div class="marker_info" id="marker_info">' +
            '<img src="' + item.map_image_url + '" alt="Image"/>' +
            '<h3>'+ item.name_point +'</h3>' +
            '<span>'+ item.description_point +'</span>' +
            '<div class="marker_tools">' +
            '<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="_blank" style="display:inline-block""><input name="saddr" value="'+ item.get_directions_start_address +'" type="hidden"><input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="'+ item.location_latitude +',' +item.location_longitude +'"><button type="submit" value="Get directions" class="btn_infobox_get_directions">Directions</button></form>' +
                '<a href="tel://'+ item.phone +'" class="btn_infobox_phone">'+ item.phone +'</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<a href="'+ item.url_point + '" class="btn_infobox">Details</a>' +
            '</div>',
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(10, 125),
            closeBoxMargin: '5px -20px 2px 2px',
            closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
            isHidden: false,
            alignBottom: true,
            pane: 'floatPane',
            enableEventPropagation: true
        });


    };
 <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
                <a href="#" class="btn_map location_map_btn properties" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="onHtmlClick(1)">View Larger Map <i class="icon-location-5"></i></a>


  <!-- The Modal map-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Search By Map</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="map_modal" class="map"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn_map location_map_btn properties" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
<!-- End modal map -->
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "markers array" is a object with the key "Single_villas", then an array of `google.maps.Markers` in that property.  To trigger a click event on a single marker your `onHtmlClick` function needs to be something like:

```
function onHtmlClick(key,key2) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[key][key2], "click");
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zpLdg6sb/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
(function(A) {

  if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
    A.forEach = A.forEach || function(action, that) {
      for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++)
        if (i in this)
          action.call(that, this[i], i, this);
    };

})(Array.prototype);

var
  mapObject,
  markers = [],
  markersData = {
    'Single_hotel': [{
        name: 'Villas',
        location_latitude: 37.713490,
        location_longitude: 20.980900,
        map_image_url: 'img/villas/280.jpg',
        name_point: 'Aeolos Luxury Villas 0',
        description_point: 'Lorem Ipsum',
        get_directions_start_address: '',
        phone: '+30 2641 085625',
        url_point: 'single_hotel.html'
      },
      {
        name: 'Villas2',
        location_latitude: 37.713,
        location_longitude: 20.980,
        map_image_url: 'img/villas/280.jpg',
        name_point: 'Aeolos Luxury Villas 1',
        description_point: 'Lorem Ipsum',
        get_directions_start_address: '',
        phone: '+30 2641 085625',
        url_point: 'single_hotel.html'
      }
    ]

  };


var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 14,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.859490, 20.925600),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

  mapTypeControl: false,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
  },
  panControl: false,
  panControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
  },
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
  },
  scrollwheel: false,
  scaleControl: false,
  scaleControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
  },
  streetViewControl: true,
  streetViewControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
  }
};
var marker;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_modal'), mapOptions);
for (var key in markersData) {
  markersData[key].forEach(function(item) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.location_latitude, item.location_longitude),
      map: mapObject,
      // icon: 'img/pins/' + key + '.png',
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    mapObject.fitBounds(bounds);
    if ('undefined' === typeof markers[key])
      markers[key] = [];
    markers[key].push(marker);
    console.log(markers);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function() {
      closeInfoBox();
      getInfoBox(item).open(mapObject, this);
      mapObject.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(item.location_latitude, item.location_longitude));
    }));
  });
}

function onHtmlClick(key, key2) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[key][key2], "click");
}

function hideAllMarkers() {
  for (var key in markers)
    markers[key].forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
};

function closeInfoBox() {
  $('div.infoBox').remove();
};

function getInfoBox(item) {
  return new InfoBox({
    content: '<div class="marker_info" id="marker_info" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: white; padding: 5px;">' +
      // '<img src="' + item.map_image_url + '" alt="Image"/>' +
      '<h3>' + item.name_point + '</h3>' +
      '<span>' + item.description_point + '</span>' +
      '<div class="marker_tools">' +
      '<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="_blank" style="display:inline-block""><input name="saddr" value="' + item.get_directions_start_address + '" type="hidden"><input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="' + item.location_latitude + ',' + item.location_longitude + '"><button type="submit" value="Get directions" class="btn_infobox_get_directions">Directions</button></form>' +
      '<br/><a href="tel://' + item.phone + '" class="btn_infobox_phone">' + item.phone + '</a>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<a href="' + item.url_point + '" class="btn_infobox">Details</a>' +
      '</div>',
    disableAutoPan: false,
    maxWidth: 0,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(10, 125),
    closeBoxMargin: '5px -20px 2px 2px',
    closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
    isHidden: false,
    alignBottom: true,
    pane: 'floatPane',
    enableEventPropagation: true
  });
};
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
}

.marker_info {
  background
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
<a href="#" class="btn_map location_map_btn properties" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="onHtmlClick('Single_hotel',0)">View Larger Map (Single_hotel[0])<i class="icon-location-5"></i></a><br>
<a href="#" class="btn_map location_map_btn properties" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="onHtmlClick('Single_hotel',1)">View Larger Map (Single_hotel[1])<i class="icon-location-5"></i></a>


<!-- The Modal map-->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Search By Map</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="map_modal" class="map"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn_map location_map_btn properties" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End modal map -->

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/googlemaps/v3-utility-library@master/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are right. It now displays the infobox on the click of the button. Thank you very much for your help. Now, I am facing the following problem.
As you see on the video below (i added the bootstrap files to your code), when i first click  and open the model with the map, the infobox with the marker is not in the center but on top. When I click again on the marker it is centered normally. Any idea? [link](https://www.loom.com/share/f55d2a9775894430b96ee8a611f4eeea)

Comment: What video? (in general, videos aren't particularly useful by themselves) However, that is another question (not suitable for the comments).

Comment: Please see fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/48e2jf3b/) . If you think is better to make a new question please inform me. I mentioned it on comments because it is related to your solution above which answered  my first question.